# Openfire XMPP - pipe a user's messages to a url

Tags: php, apache, xmpp, openfire

I'm fairly new to XMPP and Openfire and am trying to get my head round the standard way of doing things.

I'd ideally like to send any messages received by a specific XMPP user, via POST, to a URL where a PHP script can then process the message. This would all happen on my local server / local Apache installation.

I've seen that with BOSH I can make a persistent connection listening for XMPP messages through PHP, however perhaps I'm mistaken, but it doesn't sound like a very stable way of doing things - I worry that I'd either end up with multiple persistent connections or my BOSH PHP script would time out and I wont realise. I also ideally wouldn't always have the browser open and running this script!

Can anyone point me in a sensible direction to start me off? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create some chat using php, or want to intercept messages to certain user to do some custom work ?

Have you taken look at javascript for chat http://candy-chat.github.com/candy/

Maybe you will find there something that might help you move in right direction.

Comment: Its more the intercept to do certain work option (I'm happily using pidgin as the chat client). I effectively want to create a bot that you can ask questions, have these questions sent to a php script and answers will be given and/or actions performed. Example: "when's the deadline for XYZ project". Answer: ...lookup project in database with php, return deadline: "yesterday".